# PHP Undefined Index remove_junk

Tags: php, html, mysql

I know that question seems stupid but I'm still a beginner.

```
<td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($a_customers['id']))?></td>
<td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($a_customers['name']))?></td>
<td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($a_customers['company']))?></td>
<td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($a_customers['address']))?></td>
<td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($a_customers['city']))?></td>
<td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($a_customers['state']))?></td>
<td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($a_customers['country']))?></td>
<td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($a_customers['phone']))?></td>
<td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($a_customers['email']))?></td>
```

ERROR in

```
Undefined index: address in /opt/lampp/htdocs/t1/customers.php
Undefined index: state in /opt/lampp/htdocs/t1/customers.php
Undefined index: country in /opt/lampp/htdocs/t1/customers.php
Undefined index: email in /opt/lampp/htdocs/t1/customers.php
```

Comment: can you share some more code?

Comment: yes but which part

Comment: `$a_customer` do not have an address, nor an state, etc... see ShiraNai7 comment.

Comment: but a_customer have an address and email and state

Comment: check with isset() condition.